# Loop every worksheet to find matched value and paste entire row to the master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry I am new to vba. What I am trying to do is to merge different workbooks into the master workbook under the same file. After that I need to look across every worksheets in the master workbook to look for value in a particular column that matches the input value. If there is a match, then copy the entire row to the master workbook.

e.g. Sheet 2

```
PAYING  CASH    20914-351   13796   
CLOSED  AUTOPAY 10515-283   13795   
PAYING  AUTOPAY 10415-152   13794   
PAYING  CASH    10515-146   13793
```

Sheet 3

```
CLOSED  AUTOPAY 30215-037   13792   
PAYING  AUTOPAY 20914-351   13791   
PAYING  CASH    10415-221   13790
```

If the input value in sheet 2, sheet 3 matches 20914-351 in column C, then the entire row copied to the masterbook

```
PAYING  CASH    20914-351   13796

PAYING  AUTOPAY 20914-351   13791
```

I have copied from somewhere and got it working for the merging part. Thank you so much!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\Users\ISS-KTHP-001\Desktop\Accom Master File\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")

Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    WrdArray() = Split(fileName, ".")
    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0)
        total = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy     after:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets(total)

        GoTo exitFor:

    Next sheet

exitFor:
Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: And your question is? With keeping in mind that [“*Can someone help me?*” is not an actual question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)